# I mining the crypto on website .i did mutual wallet transfer they freezed my assets and my subordinates too.what to do now

Tags: wallets

I did mutual transfer in my trust wallet.mining website freezed our assets mine and my subordinates assets.now my mentor telling me to deposit the same amount which are freezed then the freezed amount will release. My 1 subordinates deposited the amount of assets the deposited amount and old assest shipted to withdrawable section now mentor is telling that rest of people shall deposite the ot will withdraw .what to do anybody suggest me